# Deobfuscate Lua scripts?

Tags: lua, deobfuscation

Does anyone know how I can deobfuscate a lua script that uses xfuscator to hide it? The obfuscation looks like this. If anyone could give me a point into the right direction on how I can get this done that would bne awesome! I didnt share the source because I wanted help figuring out how to deobfusate myself and didnt want the answer! 
https://gyazo.com/d2a9a2bcc602d1a1146491158271e3e6

Comment: Divide all these numbers (starting with 7020) by 260, convert codes to symbols, that would be the hidden lua bytecode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I de-obfuscate a Lua script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121229/how-do-i-de-obfuscate-a-lua-script)

Answer (score 5):

See that long table? That's the real code. It's a pattern you see quite often with obfuscators. Other than that, keep in mind that `_`, `__0` and such are all valid Lua identifiers, to you can have variables named like that.

`_` is a function that turns a number into a character; `__0` is a table that contains some standard functions. There's nothing special going on beyond that. If you see a `__0[1]("Hello")`, that'd be the same as `print("Hello")`; it just looks weird, because they put `print` into the `__0` table at index `1`.

Ultimately, the obfuscator just makes use of Lua features that people often don't understand well enough to understand what's going on. If you know the language though, it's all just smoke and mirrors.