# How to Deobfuscate This Lua scripts

Tags: lua, deobfuscation

Does anyone know how I can deobfuscate a lua script that uses xfuscator to hide it? The obfuscation looks like this.

```
pastebin.com/y3aaj2TM
```

I check around to learn decode this and in this [Deobfuscate Lua scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994591/deobfuscate-lua-scripts)
Must devide all number with 260 then convert to symbol??. i dont understand this one.

Comment: Pretty sure that was a joke.  The Other answer in that post though should help.

Comment: Don't use comments as an answer. Use actual answers instead.

Comment: i dont think divide all number with 260 can decode this

Comment: No, it won't. **Stop reading that comment, and read the answer instead.** Learn the difference between answers and comments. The answers appear below the area that says **Answer**. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61998430/62576) instead.

Comment: But that answer not help anything.

Comment: Yes, dividing by 260 reveals bytes of Lua 5.3 bytecode. [Deobfuscated](https://pastebin.com/zZz47129)

Comment: what should i do after divide it with 260? im already done that