# What kind of LUA encoding is that?

Tags: security, lua, decode, encode

everyone,

I am not so familiar with coding but I have been looking for hours now without answer. Maybe because I do not know what am I looking for.

I have found an LUA code with the below encoded code,

I was wondering which kind of encoding it is? Is there a specific  name for it, is there a way to decrypt it? for the curious one, it looks like :

```
return(function(aaEE_IIlIllIlII,aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI,aaEE_llIIlIIllllIl)local aaEE_IIllllIIlIIllIlIIII=string.char;local aaEE_lIlllIlIllIIIlIlIl=string.sub;local aaEE_IlIlIIIllIlIIIllllIIIIIIl=table.concat;local aaEE_IIIIIIlllIIIIllllIlIII=math.ldexp;local aaEE_IIIlIIllIIllIIlIIllIllII=getfenv or function()return _ENV end;local aaEE_lIllIIIIIllllIlIlIl=select;local aaEE_lIlIlllIllIIII=unpack or table.unpack;local aaEE_llllIlllllIlIlIl=tonumber;local function aaEE_lllIllIIIlIIlllIIll(aaEE_IIlIllIlII)local aaEE_llllIIllllIll,aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI,aaEE_lIlIlllIllIIII="","",{}local aaEE_IlIllIlllIIlIllllIll=256;local aaEE_IIllIllIIIlIIlllIIlIII={}for aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI=0,aaEE_IlIllIlllIIlIllllIll-1 do aaEE_IIllIllIIIlIIlllIIlIII[aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI]=aaEE_IIllllIIlIIllIlIIII(aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI)end;local aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI=1;local function aaEE_IlIlllllllIIlI()local aaEE_llllIIllllIll=aaEE_llllIlllllIlIlIl(aaEE_lIlllIlIllIIIlIlIl(aaEE_IIlIllIlII,aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI,aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI),36)aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI=aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI+1;local aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI=aaEE_llllIlllllIlIlIl(aaEE_lIlllIlIllIIIlIlIl(aaEE_IIlIllIlII,aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI,aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI+aaEE_llllIIllllIll-1),36)aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI=aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI+aaEE_llllIIllllIll;return aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI end;aaEE_llllIIllllIll=aaEE_IIllllIIlIIllIlIIII(aaEE_IlIlllllllIIlI())aaEE_lIlIlllIllIIII[1]=aaEE_llllIIllllIll;while aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI<#aaEE_IIlIllIlII do local aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI=aaEE_IlIlllllllIIlI()if aaEE_IIllIllIIIlIIlllIIlIII[aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI]then aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI=aaEE_IIllIllIIIlIIlllIIlIII[aaEE_lIlIIIIIlI]else aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI=aaEE_llllIIllllIll..aaEE_lIlllIlIllIIIlIlIl(aaEE_llllIIllllIll,1,1)end;aaEE_IIllIllIIIlIIlllIIlIII[aaEE_IlIllIlllIIlIllllIll]=aaEE_llllIIllllIll..aaEE_lIlllIlIllIIIlIlIl(aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI,1,1)aaEE_lIlIlllIllIIII[#aaEE_lIlIlllIllIIII+1],aaEE_llllIIllllIll,aaEE_IlIllIlllIIlIllllIll=aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI,aaEE_lIIlIlllIlllIIIllIIlIllI,aaEE_IlIllIlllIIlIllllIll+1 end;return table.concat(aaEE_lIlIlllIllIIII)end;
```

https://pastebin.com/4HU5pFHZ

Thank you for your answers and explanation

Comment: Its just obfuscated variable names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I de-obfuscate a Lua script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121229/how-do-i-de-obfuscate-a-lua-script)

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: You can undo some of the obfuscation, e.g. the parts where global variables are assigned to locals, but the original names are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Its called obfuscation (you can look up "lua obfuscator" or "script obfuscator" for more information) and just makes the code unreadable. I've already seen this obfuscation but i can't recall the name of it, its a paid one tho.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best encryption see here.

1 = Let's encrypt lua code com or: LuaEncrypt.exe.

2 = Let's chamar or encrypted lua code.

3 = To call this encrypted code, we will use AmsLuac.dll created in C++

https://github.com/AmsPluginsBox/Encrypt-Lua-Code