# How do i make a lua format file from a github raw code that is wrote in lua (i guess)?

Tags: github, lua, scripting, roblox

**the link:** https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ketamo/ybaa/main/yba

This is a script for a roblox game, but the raw code looks very strange for me. I cant understand it.

Another github raw lua script code for a roblox game: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArponAG/Scripts/main/AnimeAdventures.lua

But its clean and understandable.

So how do i decipher this:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ketamo/ybaa/main/yba

So after i can make it a lua script

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the creator of that script obfuscated it to presumably prevent others from modifying it. You can go through and try to decipher it by renaming variables and such, but it looks like the obfuscation they sent it through did a really great job of it.

If you just want to run it you should be able to still run it assuming this is the same code that runs the game.

[How do I de-obfuscate a Lua script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121229/how-do-i-de-obfuscate-a-lua-script) This question may help out.

Also in case you didn't know that link corresponds to [this repo](https://github.com/ketamo/ybaa/blob/main/yba). I found it using this other question [What do raw.githubusercontent.com URLs represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065921/what-do-raw-githubusercontent-com-urls-represent)